# React-Native / XCode : Build Failing for ffmpeg

Tags: xcode, react-native, ffmpeg

Trying to build a react-native app for ios, but build is failing due to problem below:

```
ld: in /Users/tialifouroohi/Desktop/GitHub/SocialNetworkWrapper-ReactNative/InstagramClone/ios/Pods/mobile-ffmpeg-https/libavcodec.framework/libavcodec(aacencdsp.o), building for iOS Simulator, but linking in object file built for free standing, file '/Users/tialifouroohi/Desktop/GitHub/SocialNetworkWrapper-ReactNative/InstagramClone/ios/Pods/mobile-ffmpeg-https/libavcodec.framework/libavcodec' for architecture x86_64
```

React-Native version: 0.63.2
XCode Version: 12.4
Build Target ios version: 13.6

What can I change or do to make the build succeed?

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in Podfile:

```
pod 'react-native-ffmpeg/https-lts', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-ffmpeg'
```

Disable auto-linking in react-native.config.js like this:

```
"react-native-ffmpeg": {
  platforms: {
    ios: null,
  },
},
```

Now run

```
pod install
```

Try this code ,it may fix your issue .